# How to reference ArrayList<Custom Class> type variables and objects in it with an index in Kotlin, with MVVM pattern and Data Binding applied?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, mvvm, android-databinding

I'm building an app, with MVVM pattern applied.
I've added all the required dependencies.
Also, I know how to pass variables to my xml layout files,
and how to use a function using them as parameters.
But I just don't know how to handle ArrayList type of variables.

This is the data class declaration part from my activity_main.xml

```
<variable
      name="vm"
      type="com.example.mvvm.MainActivityViewModel" />
<variable
      name="codeBlock"
      type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
<variable
      name="block"
      type="com.example.mvvm.CodeBlock" />
```

And binded the data like this in MainActivity

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)

//binds data
binding.vm = mMainActivityViewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
binding.codeBlock = mMainActivityViewModel.getBlockButton()
```

so I did pass the ArrayList of custom classes, each of them is called CodeBlock. And here's what I've tried :

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/bt_move"
      style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/move"
      android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textColor="@color/Black"
      android:onClick="@{vm.addNewBlock(codeBlock[0])}"/>
```

or not `[0]`, but `.get(0)`

and I think, or I'm sure it is because that the type of codeBlock[0] varaiable is ambiguous. In MainActivity, this thing gives me an error sign.

`var ff : CodeBlock = binding.codeBlock[0]`

`Type Mismatch , Required : CodeBlock Found : Any!`

Why??? I gave it ArrayList and it received that?

Also, this gives me an error too.

`var ff : ArrayList<CodeBlock> = binding.codeBlock`

`Smart cast to 'kotlin.collections.ArrayList<CodeBlock> /*= java.util.ArrayList<CodeBlock> */' is impossible, because 'binding.codeBlock' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time`

Well should I use `kotlin.collections.ArrayList<CodeBlock>`?
but in variable type in `activity_main.xml`,
it does not support that kind of type.
It seems it only support types from java.
I can't find `kotlin.collections.ArrayList`.
So how can I pass ArrayList type of variables to view?
And this ArrayList property? this is not gonna change. It is a list of blocks that the user can choose in a stage. So it shouldn't be Mutable.

When I try to run the code,
the error says
`cannot find method addNewBlock(java.lang.Object) in class com.example.mvvm.MainActivityViewModel`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058632/android-data-binding-two-way-binding-with-array Possible duplicate

Comment: post your view model